# How to programmatically detect whether TLS 1.3 is supported on the current OS

Tags: windows, winapi, tls1.3

I am creating custom UI for enabling/disabling the support for TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2/1.3 on OS level (for Windows).

I need to determine whether the current OS supports the different versions of TLS. I've seen the table describing [TLS support by Windows version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support), but following the guideline in [Operating System Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version):

> Identifying the current operating system is usually not the best way to determine whether a particular operating system feature is present.[...] Rather than using the Version API Helper functions to determine the operating system platform or version number, test for the presence of the feature itself.

I don't want to hard code specific version names in my code, so I am looking for way to query whether this particular feature is supported, (e.g. through the Windows API or similar).

P.S. It even seems hard to detect the actual [version of the Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version) these days, as e.g. both Windows Server 2019 and Windows Server 2022 would return `10.0`.

Comment: For more details about how to get the system version, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Getting the System Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/getting-the-system-version) 

Relying on version information is not the best way to test for a feature.

It seems that there is no suitable winapi to detect whether TLS 1.3 is supported on the current OS.